# What is it about Kotlin's fold that allows me to put the operation function after the closing parentheses?

Tags: kotlin

What is it about `Iterable.fold(...)` in Kotlin that allows me to put the `operation` function *after* the closing parentheses?

```
val numbers = listOf(5, 2, 10, 4)

// operation function passed as the second param of fold
val sumDoubled1 = numbers.fold(0, { sum, n -> sum + n * 2 })
println(sumDoubled1)

// operation function after the closing paren of fold
val sumDoubled2 = numbers.fold(0) { sum, n -> sum + n * 2 }
println(sumDoubled2)
```

Comment: It's a convenient syntax provided by Kotlin for trailing lambdas and is not specific to `fold`: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [Passing trailing lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter) means, if a methods takes last parameter input as function(aka method literal) then it can be placed outside that method call though you can also place it inside the brackets as well. A simple example would be:

```
fun main() {
    processInput("Lambda", { println(it) })
    processInput("Passing trailing lambda") { println(it) }
    processInput("Passing trailing lambda with named param") { input -> println(input) }
}

fun processInput(input:String, method:(str:String)->Unit){
    method(input.toUpperCase()) // additional logic
}
```

Output:

```
LAMBDA
PASSING TRAILING LAMBDA
PASSING TRAILING LAMBDA WITH NAMED PARAM
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to Pavneet's answer, the rationale behind this that it allows you to write what look like language extensions.  For example:

```
repeat (10) {
    // Do something
}
```

That looks like a new type of loop structure; but it's really just a function called `repeat()` that takes two parameters; an integer, and a lambda.

Also, if the lambda is the *only* parameter, you can omit the parens entirely, e.g.:

```
repeatForever {
    // Do something
}
```

(`repeat()` is in the standard library; `repeatForever()` is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

The ability to neaten some inline method calls, such as `someValue.takeIf{ it > 0 }` is just a nice side-effect of that.