# Kotlin: how can 'fold' function take one argument?

Tags: kotlin

According to the documentation of Kotlin, the function "fold" takes two arguments: an initial value and an operation. 
However, I see that the following code compiles and works well:

```
listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3).fold(0) { x, y -> x + y }
```

There is only one argument inside the parenthesis, instead of two. If so, how is it possible that the code's compilation succeeds? it should be an error.

Answer (score 3):

[According docs:](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter)

> In Kotlin, there is a convention: if the last parameter of a function
>   is a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding
>   argument can be placed outside the parentheses.

and

> If the lambda is the only argument to that call, the parentheses can be omitted entirely.

This feature, called `trailing lambda`, makes the code hard to understand for novice Kotlin developers, but when you get it, it allows writting DSL-like code, like this:

```
val person = person {
    name = "John"
    age = 25
    address {
        street = "Main Street"
        number = 42
        city = "London"
    }
}
```

And that's why it is such a powerful language feature.

Comment: Thanks. And this convention is a horrible idea and I hope that it will be reverted soon.

Comment: I didn't like either at the beggining, but now, I find it a nice syntax sugar.

Comment: It makes the code neither shorter nor more readable and make the code hard-to-understand for novice Kotlin developers.

Comment: You can be pretty sure it won't be removed and break all the code written using it.

Comment: After you start using lots of higher order functions and chained calls, you will love it. ;)

Comment: There are good reasons for allowing this syntax; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60385682/10134209) to a related question.